# MacBook Pro turns off when battery is around 20% and Android Studio tries to build an app

Tags: macos, android, battery, macbook, android-studio

I have a MacbookPro 15' 2019 (core i9), and something weird is happening to me. When my Macbook is unplugged and the battery is around 20% or lower, if I open AndroidStudio and start building an application, my Macbook screen is turned off. It's hard to say whether it was shutdown or just entered sleep mode for a while, I have to wait for some seconds (the screen is completely black) and suddenly the screen is turned on again (wi-fi appears like trying to reconnect but all my applications are in there, like if nothing have happened). This behavior keeps happening while I am running something in AndroidStudio until I plug the computer. Once that happen it works well.

It is so weird, I've been investigating and found that it could be a disk/memory issue, but I do not know how to explain that it happens only when the MacBook is unplugged with <= 20% of battery. I tried running Android Studio with my computer plugged and with 5% and works under normal conditions.

Is there anyone experiencing this behavior?

Note 1: Battery health according to OS X, it is Normal.

Note 2: OSX Version: Catalina 10.15.6 Android Studio Version: 4.0.1 (the same happened to me when I was using the last 3.x version)

Note 3: The battery has less than 1 year old, I bought the laptop in November 2019, so, it is around 9 months. I tried other things like VSCode & Safari & Terminal under same conditions and no issues found. Btw, I am not sure if this is actually a crash, or MacBook just go sleep, or is turned off. I tried to look for crash report and did not find anything (haven't seen the death screen either), and the screen appears again after around 15 - 20 seconds without the apple logo, it just appear as it was with all the screens opened in the same desktops, but with Wi-Fi trying to reconnect.

Any suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: Sounds like it is sleeping to me.

Comment: Sounds like when the CPU goes to max it doesn't have enough power to run everything and is shedding load rather than a hard shutdown.

Comment: Is there any workaround or something to deal with that? or it is just the accepted behavior for Macs :(

Comment: Hi, I got the same issue today even with 45% of battery (unplugged). Is there anyone who can help?